# How to get Instagram post id by using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get 11 character post id based on Regex expression. In my code I added two Instagram URL written in different ways, I want a proper Regex expression which gives me 11 characters post id. The Regex expression I am using is not giving proper results.

**JsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/z5huq2aL/

**Code:**

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  
var userURL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CBnwdW5n2VA/";
var userURL1 = "https://www.instagram.com/angelinajolie_offiicial/p/CBnwdW5n2VA/";

var regExp = /(https?:\/\/www\.)?instagram\.com(\/p\/\w+\/?)/;

var match = userURL.match(regExp);
var match1 = userURL.match(regExp);

alert(match);
alert(match1);
  
}</script>
```

Comment: You don't need most of that regex. Just `/\/p\/(.*?)\//` will do. Then just get `match[1]` for the sub-pattern (which is the ID you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should solve your issue:

```
function myFunction() {


var userURL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CBnwdW5n2VA/";
var userURL1 = "https://www.instagram.com/angelinajolie_offiicial/p/CBnwdW5n2VA/";

var regExp = /\/p\/(.*?)\//;

var match = userURL.match(regExp);
var match1 = userURL.match(regExp);

alert(match[1]);
alert(match1[1]);
  
}
```

working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/narkhedetusshar/u2xgh0r5/

Answer (score 4):

Use a single capturing group and place the `/p/` and the trailing `/` outside of the group.

If you want to match 11 word chars, use `\w{11}`, else `\w+` would suffice.

Assuming the url does not contain whitespace chars, you could use `\S*?` to match until the first occurrence of `/p/`

**Note** that the first part is optional and is not anchored. It matches the `http://www.` if it is there, but when it is not there, or something else is there, you could still get a partial match for the rest of the pattern.

```
(?:https?:\/\/www\.)?instagram\.com\S*?\/p\/(\w{11})\/?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJQ7Sq/1)

```js
var userURL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CBnwdW5n2VA/";
var userURL1 = "https://www.instagram.com/angelinajolie_offiicial/p/CBnwdW5n2VA/";

var regExp = /(?:https?:\/\/www\.)?instagram\.com\S*?\/p\/(\w{11})\/?/;

var match = userURL.match(regExp);
var match1 = userURL.match(regExp);

console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match1[1]);
```

Comment: IDs can contain dashes `-` so the word flag won't catch them